# Group and Order By

Tags: mysql

I'm unsure if I'm using the `GROUP BY` function correctly, What I'm trying to achieve is for this query to select the latest input from the table and group them by the `username`, Below I have attached my query, the example database and the output I would like to achieve.

**SQL**

```
 SELECT * FROM `test_pms`
 WHERE `username` = 'Lewis'
 GROUP BY `username`
 ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

**Database Structure**

[image]

**Current Output**

Lewis | hi

**Desired Output**

Lewis | hi :)

Hopefully I have outlined the issue I'm having with the `GROUP BY` I'm wondering If I'm using the `ORDER BY` incorrectly in accordance with the `GROUP BY`, Thankyou for any help.

Comment: Why don't you use MAX(id)?

Comment: `Select x.* from mytable x order by id desc limit 1`. If that's not what you want, consider improving the quality of your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specified a `username` like 'lewis', then you can do it like this:

```
select *
from `test_pms`
where `username` = 'lewis'
order by `id` desc
limit 1
```

And if you want get latest record by each `username` group, you can do it like this:

```
SELECT `test_pms`.*
FROM `test_pms`
INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id, username FROM `test_pms` GROUP BY username) t
ON t.id = `test_pms`.id AND t.username = `test_pms`.username
GROUP BY `test_pms`.`username`
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/550f1/1)

Comment: Thankyou, exactly what I was after :) Really appreciate it